laravel - how to use two FK's to same table
I have a Ticket model that needs to refer PriceTable two times. One for SELL PRICE and another for REPAY PRICE (different entries).
So I'm doing this:
# Ticket model
public function priceTableSell()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\PriceTable', 'pricetable_sell_id');
}

public function priceTableRepay()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\PriceTable', 'pricetable_repay_id');
}

# PriceTable model
public function ticketsSell()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Ticket', 'pricetable_sell_id');
}

public function ticketsRepay()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Ticket', 'pricetable_repay_id');
}

The first FK was created this way:
Schema::table('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('pricetable_repay_id')
          ->unsigned()
          ->index()
          ->nullable();

    $table->foreign('pricetable_repay_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('price_tables');
});

Now I'm about to create the second foreign key but I realized that one relation already exists on database with the name tickets_price_table_id_foreign.
The question is:

do I have to rename this relation before creating another one? or manage it another way?
is this the correct way to two connections with same tables?


You can set a custom foreign name in the second argument of foreign(). Having 2 columns being a foreign to the same table is fine. If it's the best solution depends. If you only have 1 sell and 1 repay price table, it makes sense to me.

Agreed with the above; you can modify the name, and multiple FKs between 2 tables is common (created_by/updated_by both pointing to a users table, etc.) Sidenote, what version of Laravel are you on? Models haven't been in the App namespace for a while now (moved to App\Models), and convention is to use hasMany(Model::class, ...) instead of '\App\Model'; if you're on an older version, you might want to consider upgrading
